# JqueryUI hide with effect and keep space

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to hide an element with an effect using jquery UI, but I'd like the space the element is taking to stay after the element is hidden.
I don't want to use the visibility property, as I'm using an effect as follows:

```
$(".element").hide("explode");
```

I tried using this:
https://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.effects.createPlaceholder/
as follows:

```
jQuery.effects.createPlaceholder(".element");
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.css is not a function
>       at Object.createPlaceholder (jquery-ui.js:8)
>       at Object.success (myfile.html:317)
>       at c (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at l (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a jQuery Object as the element.

> **element**
>
> Type: jQuery
>
> The element to create a placeholder for.

See example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("#effect").hide("explode", function() {
      $.effects.createPlaceholder($("#effect"));
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#button {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#effect {
  width: 240px;
  height: 170px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  position: relative;
}

#effect h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Hide</h3>
  <p>Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.</p>
</div>
<button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Run Effect</button>
```

If you use just `"#effect"`, the script fails with an error. The button will then shift to the top when the animation is complete. Passing in `$("#effect")`, the script is run properly, the placeholder element is created.